# How do these SERPs display directory information in rich-snippet without sitelinks? (two example screenshots)

Tags: seo, rich-snippets, directory, sitelinks, directory-listing

Here are two examples of directory sites which have rich-snippets. How do these sites display directory information (local business contact info) in the SERP listing without using site-links?

In other words, how is "Gabrield Park Veterinary Clinic" in the SERP listing when it is not a site-link? Same goes for "A Place for Healing" below.

*See highlighted text in attached screenshots.*

[image: Organic Rich-snippet]

[image: Organic Rich-snippet #2]

Comment: You can use Schema plugin if you're running WordPress site.

Answer (score 1):

First I think you are getting a bit confused. Sitelinks aren't connected with rich snippets. They are different things:

[Sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en)

[About rich snippets and structured data](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en)

On the https://oregonvma.org/ site, these aren't rich snippets, as the page has no mark up. It's simply the content from the page being displayed in the SERPS:

Compare the content on the top of the page with your SERP screen shot:

[image]

[image]

I can' comment on the other site, as I cant find the URL.

Comment: More specifically, the Oregon site is getting a "list snippet", as detailed on Google's _Inside Search_ here: http://insidesearch.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/new-snippets-for-list-pages.html

Comment: Thanks for your help @Moobot. Is the VetStreet snippet also generated because it is in list format?

Comment: The Vetstreet site does actually have Structured Data that can generate rich snippets. You can check URLs for Structured Data with this tool: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets